# Usage of a participial construction in a specific interrogative sentence

Tags: construction

I cannot grasp the construction and meaning of the following sentence.

"What do Company A and Company B intend to achieve, anticipating that their intentions may be somewhat different?"

Could you please teach me the construction and who is anticipating in the sentence?
I have never seen this kind of sentence before.
I have no idea what is the subject of "is anticipating."
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read out of context, it's not a very clear sentence, but I would suggest that the *writer* expects (anticipates) that the intentions of Comapny A are different from the intentions of Company B, and *vice versa*.

Comment: @Trevor, can that sentence be a *dangling participle* construct, which, as is well known, create a lot of difficulties in understanding to English speakers?

Comment: @Trevor, I know that you cannot understand, but if you had studied Italian you wouldn't have had any problem in understanding that sentence.

Comment: @Trevor, in fact we identify "anticipating" as a gerund, whose semantic meaning and whose function are pretty clear.

Comment: It is one of several bullet-point sentences and in the context of how best two companies should collaborate on a project.

Answer (score 2):

As TrevorD observed, the sentence is far from clear.  No wonder you are having difficulty with it!

By re-casting the sentence, I might make the writer's meaning clearer.  For example,

> "Since their intentions are likely different, Company A and Company B will not likely achieve anything [in my opinion]."

Or,

> "I cannot tell what Company A and Company B intend to achieve, given their different intentions." [or "It is difficult to tell what . . .."]

Or,

> "What do Company A and Company B hope to achieve, knowing their intentions are different?"

Or,

> "Knowing that Company A and Company B have different intentions, I wonder what they hope to achieve."

Or, in order to keep the notion of anticipation in the sentence,

> Knowing that Companies A and B already anticipate their intentions to be different, I wonder what they intend [hope] to achieve."

Or,

> "Given that Companies A and B already anticipate their intentions to be somewhat different, what do they intend [hope] to achieve?"

Comment: rhetor, I think that "anticipated" in the OP's sentence is supposed to mean "to speak or write in knowledge or expectation of later matter", but I don't see which of your versions fits this definition. Can you clarify, please?

Comment: The Italian *anticpare* could be translated into: "predicting"= "telling ahead of time" (If this helps?) Not 100% certain.

Comment: @Carlo_R.:  Good point.  I'll edit my answer by adding a fifth example.

Comment: It is one of several bullet-point sentences.

Comment: The context is about how best the two companies should collaborate on a project.

Answer (score 0):

I have read all the comments, and the extensive answer by @rhetorician.

One thing seems to me abundantly clear above all else. ***Anticipating*** is a malapropism. The word the writer probably wanted was ***recognising***. If you replace one with the other, the sentence immediately makes more sense.

Though I still think I might have said it differently.